# Pyinstaller works on build machines, but not on target machines

Tags: pyinstaller

I am using pyinstaller to distribute a python program.  It's work fine on my build machine, but on my target machines, I am getting a "path not found" error and the path is relative (.e.g.  .\mylib).  I do modify the sys.path at runtime, but I have taken the steps suggested by pyinstaller to account for that.  I've also tried -add-data, but -add-data seems to make things worse and I get errors where files are being created twice.

What's is bizarre to me is that if I run the python script on the target machine once,  (i.e. install python), the EXE created by pyinstaller by the build machine will now work on the target machine.  I can then remove python from this machine and.... the exe continues to work.  My next step is to start a VM and follow the debug steps from the guide, but thought I would reach out and see if anyone had some advice on what my cause this?

Comment: based on your description alone, there could be any number of different issues causing your issues.  Is your project private?

Comment: Yes it is and it's also very large.  I've tried most of the things suggested by pyinstaller, so I'd be happy to hear any suggestions.  I can also see if I can reduce the project to the heart of the matter and make a public version for help.  Thank you for your response!

Comment: If you have it saved to a public repo on github or something you can post a link...

Comment: If not please create [example]